# Missing /dev/ram0 /dev/ram1 and /proc/kcore

Tags: linux, centos, ramdisk

I have been experimenting with `etckeeper` to store different snapshots of `/etc` in a git repo.

I have cloned a working `/etc` in `/etc-1` of a clean VPS and I have restored metadata with `etckeeper`, the I have deleted `/etc` and I have made a symbolic link of `/etc` to `/etc-1`.

I could not connect from ssh after reboot, so I logged in from the HN.

Searching for broken symlinks I have found that `/etc/dev/devices/ram` and `/etc/dev/devices/ramdisk` have broken links to `/dev/ram1` and `/dev/ram0`. And `/dev/core` has a broken symlink to `/proc/kcore`.

I can create the ramdisks with :

```
mknod -m 660 /dev/ram0 b 1 1
chown root.disk /dev/ram0
```

But when I reboot they disappear.

What creates all those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are created if the system has a ramdisk. I doubt that's the source of your problem though. Go back in time: before you delete `/etc`, compare `/etc` and `/etc-1` with `diff -q` to see if etckeeper really cloned `/etc` fully.

Comment: I guess some lost config file in /etc is to blame. the diff gives quite an amount of them. I have not been able to pinoint the issue like that

Comment: It appears it is an issue with udev. I am investigating it

Comment: So, udev does not run at boot. It creates blocks devices during the installation, then creates new ones on demand. Icopied all block devices from a sane /etc and everything worked again.
Conclusion: it is not possible to restore /etc with etckeeper starting with an empty /etc